# Place for AES encryption keys in web project

Tags: c, .net, encryption, asp.net-core, aes

I build web application with .net Core 2.0

I have to encrypt some data with AES algorithm, and there is a question. I have IV and key but where I should store keys to be sure if the keys are secure?

Should I store this keys in code? If yes where is the best place for it?

Comment: Storing in the code is definitely a very bad option. This basically means you give the key away. It's just like putting the key of your house under the doormat.

Comment: There is no way to store keys securely. The longer you store them, the less secure such storage becomes. You can consider using random keys each time or public-key cryptography.

Comment: Provide more information about *why* you need to encryption information.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It doesn't matter if he put the key inside his code or a config file. He by design have to give the key "away", which like you wrote is bad.

Comment: So what it the solution? If I want have encrypted data?

Comment: You want to have the least possible amount of access to the key that can be used for decryption. The harder it is for an attacker to get to it, the better it is protected. And yes, getting to the source *may* be harder than getting to the data. But there are also system key stores, hardware modules etc. Actually, books have been written about *key management*. Configuring the key management system is one of the hardest things about creating a secure system. There is not one good answer, there are basically a lot of average to bad answers because in the end you need to use the key.